# t-sql grouping rows between ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query that returns Quantity based discount list

```
with cte([item code],price,discount,rngLow,rngHigh,id) as

    (
    select 'xxx-xxxxxxx' as [item code],l.t$pric,l.t$disc,lqanp=l.t$qanp,hqanp=h.t$qanp,id = row_number() over(partition by h.t$qanp order by h.t$qanp) from EdiCatalog l
    join ediCatalog h on l.comno=h.comno and l.t$cpls=h.t$cpls and  l.t$cuno=h.t$cuno and h.t$item=l.t$item  and l.t$qanp < h.t$qanp 

     where l.comno=@comno and l.t$cpls=@cpls and l.t$cuno=@cuno  
    )
    select * from cte
```

returning result set

[image]

How do I transform the result set to this

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should explain the logic behind that aggregation. There are lot of rows with the same percentages in the original result set. What is the logic with which you want to build those ranges and choose a percentage?

Comment: @Frazz , the aggregate I am looking for should eliminate repeating rows with rngLow, means rngLow =1 should not be repeated,likewise 9 and 23.

Comment: And of the many rows with the same rngLow... which will you keep? The one with the lowest rngHigh? Please be specific.

Comment: @Frazz, second snapshot depicts the results I am looking for, I guess it could be done within the cte query, but I could not figure how to..

Comment: I saw the second snapshot. But there are many ways to get there. If you are not able to illustrate the logic behind that desired result set, then you do not really know what you are asking us.

Comment: @Frazz,I really do not know of better way to explain what I want..,Of many ways you think, give me the best.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte a
WHERE rngHigh=(
  SELECT MIN(rngHigh)
  FROM cte b
  WHERE b.rngLow=a.rngLow
)
```

Which will give you this result set:

```
discount    rngLow  rngHigh
40            1       9
68            9      23
73           23      47
75           47     299
```

Comment: Thanks .. I revised that a little as follows, and I have the desired results, thanks once again..SELECT rngLow=case rngLow 
          when 1 then rnglow
          else rnglow+1 end,rngHigh,discount,id
FROM cte a
WHERE rngHigh=(
  SELECT MIN(rngHigh)
  FROM cte b
  WHERE b.rngLow=a.rngLow
)

Answer (score 0):

@Frazz,
Here is what I have now
[image]

with little alteration to what you suggested..

```
SELECT rngLow=case rngLow 
                                        when 1 then rnglow
                                        else rnglow+1 end,rngHigh,discount,id
FROM cte a
WHERE rngHigh=(
  SELECT MIN(rngHigh)
  FROM cte b
  WHERE b.rngLow=a.rngLow
)
```